# user does not have access to folder even if he is in a group with full control

Tags: windows-10, file-permissions

I figured out a super secure (ransomware proof) backup solution using free Syncrify backup software. It looks like it is working BUT now when I want to check something if it is in that folder I runas cmd as the user backuper but can't access it!

```
D:\zaloha>cd Syncrify
Přístup byl odepřen.

D:\zaloha>whoami
athena\backuper

D:\zaloha>cacls syncrify
D:\zaloha\Syncrify BUILTIN\Backup Operators:(OI)(CI)F

D:\zaloha>net localgroup "backup operators"
Název aliasu     backup operators
Komentář         Člen skupiny Backup Operators může pro účely zálohování a obnovování dat překonat zabezpečující omezení.

Členové

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
backuper
Příkaz byl úspěšně dokončen.
```

So why the heck can't I access the folder when running cmd asi backuper user which is member of Backup Operators group which has full control for this folder?? Then I tried to add specifically backuper user to this folder permissions and suddenly I can access it. Is this group somehow broken on my Windows 10 machine? The syncrify service runs under backuper user and happily writes data to this folder. Why can't I access it using cmd is a mystery for me.

Answer (score 0):

`Backup Operators` is one of the groups that is affected by UAC, like `administrators` you have to elevate the command prompt to get the full `Backup Operators` permissions.

Run a:

```
whoami /groups
```

you will see that `Backup Operators` is `Group used for deny only` unless you elevate the command prompt first.

I'm pretty sure this has been the case since Windows Vista, nothing new in Windows 10.

Comment: sorry for late answer. What do you exactly mean by elevating the command prompt to get Backup Operators full permissions? I can run command prompt (administrator) from start, but how is it different from using runas? I can see that Backup Operators group have specific rights in secpol.msc local policies / local rights assignment

Comment: `Runas` runs a process as a different user, but not elevated, if you log in as a member of the `Backup Operators` and then the run `command prompt (administrator)` you should get access. Even though you are not an administrator but now have an elevated cmd.exe